Based on a given date range, find the period "Period Beginning Date" for a given date outside the provided range
Need to write a formula that returns the "Pay Period Beginning" Date using the provided Pay Period Dates in C5 and D5. The number of days in the given pay period is in E5 (as of writing this, currently 14). So I need to find the beginning date of the 14 day period for thes dates inputed into column C.
Need to write this as an arrayformula that outputs down a column.
Link to Sheet



You may try:
=vstack("Header",
 map(C8:C,lambda(Σ,if(Σ="",,C5+(E5*int(days(Σ,C5)/E5))))))



Much more efficient than my own answer. Thank you!

I believe I was able to answer my own question (Putting formula in cell H7):
=LET(header, "Lands on Pay Period Beginning: ", dateOutsidePeriod, $C$8:$C, periodBegin, $C$5, periodEnding, $D$5, numDaysInPeriod, DATEDIF(periodBegin, periodEnding, "D") + 1, numDaysBetweenEndOfPeriodAndInput, ARRAYFORMULA(IF(dateOutsidePeriod = "", ,IF((dateOutsidePeriod >= periodBegin)*(dateOutsidePeriod <= periodEnding), "In Current Period", DATEDIF(IF(dateOutsidePeriod >= periodEnding, periodEnding, dateOutsidePeriod), IF(dateOutsidePeriod >= periodEnding, dateOutsidePeriod, periodEnding), "D")))), numPeriodsBetweenEndOfPeriodAndInputedDate, ARRAYFORMULA(IF(numDaysBetweenEndOfPeriodAndInput = "", ,IFERROR(IF(dateOutsidePeriod >= periodEnding, ROUNDUP((numDaysBetweenEndOfPeriodAndInput)/numDaysInPeriod), ROUNDDOWN((numDaysBetweenEndOfPeriodAndInput)/numDaysInPeriod)) , "In Current Period"))),numDaysBetweenEndOfOayPeriodAndEndOfLandingPeriod, ARRAYFORMULA(IF(numPeriodsBetweenEndOfPeriodAndInputedDate = "", ,IF((numPeriodsBetweenEndOfPeriodAndInputedDate <= 0)+(numPeriodsBetweenEndOfPeriodAndInputedDate = "In Current Period"),"In Current Period" ,IFERROR((numPeriodsBetweenEndOfPeriodAndInputedDate*numDaysInPeriod)*IF(dateOutsidePeriod >= periodBegin, 1, -1))))), finalResult, ARRAYFORMULA(IF(numDaysBetweenEndOfOayPeriodAndEndOfLandingPeriod = "", ,IF((numDaysBetweenEndOfOayPeriodAndEndOfLandingPeriod = "In Current Period"),periodBegin ,IFERROR(periodBegin + (numDaysBetweenEndOfOayPeriodAndEndOfLandingPeriod))))), {header; finalResult})

